# Given coordinates of the vertices of regular tetrahedron $ABCD$, find $E$ such that $ABCE$ is also a regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

> The points $A = (-1,1,1),$ $B = (1,-1,1),$ $C = (1,1,-1),$ and $D = (-1,-1,-1)$ form the vertices of a regular tetrahedron. Find the coordinates of the point $E,$ other than $D,$ such that $ABCE$ is also a regular tetrahedron.

Since we know this is a regular tetrahedron, all edges have the same length, namely $2\sqrt(2)$. We can let $E = (x,y,z)$, but this will lead to some messy equations, how can we ideally solve this?

Comment: Just set a mirror in the right place :)

Comment: Hint: look at a D8 - an 8-sided die.

Comment: Hint: Think about how the original 4th vertex, D, is related to the vertices A, B, C.

Comment: The vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are four of the eight vertices of a cube of side $2$ cantered at the origin. Each of the six edges of the tetrahedron $ABCD$ is a diagonal of one of the faces of this cube. This may help you with visualization.

Comment: I would guess E is (1,1,1) on symmetrical basis.

Comment: @SeanRoberson By D8 do you mean a square (8-sided) bipyramid? I think a triangular (6-sided) bipyramid would be more relevant here? Or did you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane containing $A,B,C$ is $\pi:\, x+y+z=1$. The line joining $D$ to the vertex you are looking for goes through the origin by symmetry. Call $P$ its intesection with the plane $\pi$. The distance $DP$ from $D$ to the plane is $4/\sqrt{3}$ (formula for plane-point distance). The vector $DP=(1,1,1)/\sqrt{3}\cdot 4/\sqrt{3}=(4/3,4/3,4/3)$. Therefore $E=D+2DP=(5/3,5/3,5/3)$.

Comment: +1. Observing that $P$ must be the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ gets you to $P=\frac13(A+B+C)=\frac13(1,1,1)$ without dealing with the plane.

Comment: @GReyes, this was a very good explanation, thank you! :)

Comment: Alternatively, the distance relations from e to the other points being 2sqrt(2), was also an approach, but lead to some tedious algebra.